# Problem in rails server starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i tried to start my rails application. it started by the webpage didn't load. Anybody know the reason and please tell me how to solve this issue

```
Error in browser:

Application error
Change this error message for exceptions thrown outside of an action (like in Dispatcher setups or broken Ruby code) in public/500.html

Error in log:

=> Booting WEBrick...
[2011-05-27 14:11:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-05-27 14:11:08] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11) [i686-linux]
[2011-05-27 14:11:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13827 port=3001
=> Rails application started on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server; call with --help for options
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2011:14:11:10 IST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 309
- -> /
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the log file `log/development.log` say? Maybe a problem with the Ruby version, with missing Ruby gems, or with the database.